# Simple .cfg parser

Tags: c++, parsing

I'm currently working to implement a simple configuration file parser. I intend to add more functional down the road.

**ConfigReader.hpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class ConfigReader
{
    public:
        struct record
        {
            std::string section;
            std::string name;
            std::string value;
        };

        ConfigReader();

        explicit ConfigReader (const std::string & file);

        bool readfile (const std::string & file);

        std::string get_string (const std::string & tsection, 
        const std::string & tname, std::string tdefault = std::string());

private:
    std::vector<record> records;
};
```

**ConfigReader.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include "ConfigReader.hpp"

namespace
{
/* Erases leading tabs, leading spaces; trailing tabs, trailing spaces. */
std::string & trim (std::string & str)
{
    // leading tabs / spaces
    int i = 0;

    while (i < (int) str.length() && (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\t'))
        ++i;

    // erase leading tabs / spaces
    if (i > 0)
        str.erase (0, i);

    int j = i = str.length();

    while (i > 0 && (str[i - 1] == ' ' || str[i - 1] == '\t'))
        --i;

    // erase trailing tabs / spaces
    if (i < j)
        str.erase (i, j);

    return str;
}

/* Erases tabs and spaces between the variable's name and its value. */
std::string & normalize (std::string & str)
{
    // Erases leading tabs, leading spaces; trailing tabs, trailing spaces.
    trim (str);

    // i is the start of the section of tabs and spaces.
    // j is the end of said section.
    std::size_t i, j;
    i = j = 0;

    while (i < str.length())
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\t')
        {
            j = i + 1;

            // find the end of section of tabs and spaces.
            while (j < str.length() && (str[j] == ' ' || str[j] == '\t'))
                ++j;

            // if the section consists of just one character,
            // then erase just one character.
            // otherwise, remove j - i characters.
            if (j == i)
                str.erase (i, 1);
            else
                str.erase (i, j - i);
        }
        else
        {
            str[i] = std::tolower (str[i]);
            ++i;
        }
    }

    return str;
}

/* Check if a line consists only of spaces and tabs */
bool spaceonly (const std::string & line)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = line.length(); i < j; ++i)
    {
        if (line[i] != ' ' && line[i] != '\t')
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

/* Check if a line is valid */
bool isvalid (std::string & line)
{
    normalize (line);
    std::size_t i = 0;

    // if the line is a section
    if (line[i] == '[')
    {
        // find where the section's name ends
        std::size_t j = line.find_last_of (']');

        // if the ']' character wasn't found, then the line is invalid.
        if (j == std::string::npos)
            return false;

        // if the distance between '[' and ']' is equal to one,
        // then there are no characters between section brackets -> invalid line.
        if (j - i == 1)
            return false;
    }

    /* Check if a line is a comment */
    else if (line[i] == ';' || line[i] == '#' || (line[i] == '/' && line[i + 1] == '/'))
        return false;

    /* Check if a line is ill-formed */
    else if (line[i] == '=' || line[i] == ']')
        return false;

    else
    {
        std::size_t j = line.find_last_of ('=');

        if (j == std::string::npos)
            return false;

        if (j + 1 >= line.length())
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// parse the line and write the content to our vector
void parse (std::vector<ConfigReader::record> & records, std::string & section, std::string & line)
{
    std::size_t i = 0;

    // if the line is a section
    if (line[i] == '[')
    {
        ++i;
        std::size_t j = line.find_last_of (']') - 1;

        section = line.substr (i, j);
    }
    // if the line is a variable + value
    else
    {
        ConfigReader::record temp;
        temp.section = section;

        // construct the name of the variable
        std::size_t j = line.find ('=');
        std::string name = line.substr (i, j);
        temp.name = name;

        // construct the variable's value
        std::size_t k = line.find ('=') + 1;
        std::size_t z = line.find (';');
        z = (z == std::string::npos) ? line.length() : z;
        std::string value = line.substr (k, z); // bug ? if the line is width = 32; then the semicolon is not erased.
        temp.value = value;

        records.push_back (temp);
    }
    }
}

bool ConfigReader::readfile (const std::string & file)
{
    records.clear();

    std::ifstream config (file);

    if (!config.is_open())
        return false;

    std::string section;
    std::string buffer;

    std::size_t i = 0;

    while (std::getline (config, buffer, '\n'))
    {
        if (!spaceonly (buffer))
        {
            if (isvalid (buffer))
                parse (records, section, buffer);
            else{}
            //                std::cout << "Failed at line " << i;
        }

        ++i;
    }

    return true;
}

std::string ConfigReader::get_string (const std::string & tsection,
                                  const std::string & tname, std::string tdefault)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < records.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (records[i].section == tsection && records[i].name == tname)
        {
            return records[i].value;
        }
    }

    record temp;
    temp.section = tsection;
    temp.name = tname;
    temp.value = tdefault;
    records.push_back (temp);

    return tdefault;
}

ConfigReader::ConfigReader (const std::string & file) : records()
{
    readfile (file);
}

ConfigReader::ConfigReader() : records()
{

}
```

The syntax of the config file is simple:

```
[video]
width = 1920;
etc;
```

What should I change? Improve? Are there any errors? (Well, there is one in parse.)

Comment: Consider using a standard format: like Json. It makes it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use standard algorithms where applicable. For instance, `trim` could be rewritten:

```
std::string& trim(std::string& s) {
  auto is_whitespace = [] (char c) -> bool { return c == ' ' || c == '\t'; };
  auto first_non_whitespace = std::find_if_not(begin(s), end(s), is_whitespace);
  s.erase(begin(s), first_non_whitespace);
  auto last_non_whitespace = std::find_if_not(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), is_whitespace)
      .base();
  s.erase(std::next(last_non_whitespace), end(s));
  return s;
}
```

Likewise, `normalize` could be written like this:

```
std::string& normalize(std::string& s) {
    s.erase(std::remove_if(begin(s), end(s),
                           [] (char c) { return c == ' ' || c == '\t'; }),
            end(s));
    std::transform(begin(s), end(s), begin(s),
                   [] (char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
    return s;
}
```

Note that the intent of this code is quite clear -- I didn't need to add comments to let you know what each section of the code was meant to be doing (although it is necessary to know standard C++ algorithms and idioms like erase-remove). It took me a few minutes of careful reading to realize that you were removing all whitespace in your `normalize` function; my version makes this very clear. Are you sure you want to remove all whitespace? Couldn't some future configuration use string types?

PS I chose to use C++11 features like `auto` and lambda, but this code can be written in C++03 with not very much more boilerplate code.

---

In `isvalid`, you declare `std::size_t i = 0`. This is confusing for a couple of reasons. When I see a variable declared non-`const`, I expect that it will change. Even if it were `const`, `i` is not meaningful here. Use `0` instead of `i` throughout that function to make it more readable. Likewise, your use of `j` is not self-documenting. I expect `i` and `j` to be loop variables. For `j` it's a bit more forgivable because it has such a narrow scope, but `last_bracket` is a name that tells me what the variable is actually for.

Also, throughout `isvalid`, you dereference `line[0]` and `line[1]`, but line might be empty after normalization. Even if you think that's not the case because of `spaceonly` guarding it, you should add an assertion that documents the precondition. As it stands, your code will access out-of-bounds memory when the line contains only whitespace and a single `'/'`.

---

`get_string` has funny semantics. For one thing, if my config file is

```
[Video]
Foo = Bar
```

I will get an empty string when calling `getline("Video", "Foo")` because you normalize the configuration file but not the queries.

Why do you store a default value if the query fails to find a record? This is not behavior I would expect; in fact, I'd expect `get_string` to be declared `const`. If you insist on storing a temp value, you should add a constructor for `record` and rewrite the storage as `records.push_back(record(tsection, tname, tdefault));`; in modern compilers, this will result in no copy being made while your version requires a copy.

You should also consider a different data structure. There are a few reasonable options.

- Keep using a `vector`, but sort it and use `lower_bound` to do lookups.
- Use a `map` keyed on section or section and name.
- Use an `unordered_map`.

It depends on future class features, the expected size of config files, and the frequency of insertions, but the `vector` approach is almost certainly best -- see [this blog entry](http://yaserzt.com/blog/archives/615) for example.

---

This list is not exhaustive, but it should get you started.

Comment: Hey. Thanks. I am well aware of lamdas. I have been programming for about a year and it is a bad habit of mine of not using STL algrorithms.

Comment: I have already been thinking of using a map, btw. I will accept your answer.:)